# Access UINavigation Controller from the app delegate

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

From appDelegate I want to access a view controller which is embedded with UINavigation controller.

How can I do so, knowing that I can directly access that view controller but in this case the navigation bar will not appear, therefore this is not what I want.

I have tried the code found below but it prompts a warning and a black screen is presented.

```
var storyboard1 = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        var viewController: ExamNav_ViewController = storyboard1.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ExamNav_ViewController") as! ExamNav_ViewController
        var rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
   // rootViewController.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
    rootViewController.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The warning is: Attempt to present PlayMyWay.ExamNav_ViewController: 0x14fd19b50 on UINavigationController: 0x14fd13a90 whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
let navController: UINavigationController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("provaNavController") as UINavigationController
window?.rootViewController = navController
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

More [Click here to learn about that](https://gist.github.com/snikch/3661188)

Answer (score 0):

```
var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
var objOrderVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ExamNav_ViewController") as! ExamNav_ViewController
                    let navig = UINavigationController(rootViewController: objOrderVC)
                    navig.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)
                    window?.rootViewController = navig
```